# mysql query to select comments from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. **comments(comments_id, comment, user, flag)** and table **hide_comment(id, user, the_comment_id)**. Table comments holds all comments posted by users. Table hide_comment used to keep track for all posts that a user wants to hide.  For example if **$session_user_id=23** want to hide a comment with **comments_id=1209** a have a php that places $session_user_id and comments_id into hide_comment table. In order to show in user's blog all comments except those that are hidden, I want a mysql query that it would selects all comments from table **comments** , except those in table **hide_comment** that the user denotes that wants to hide. Any idea what mysql_query should be?

This is what I have done until now:

```
<?php 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 40") or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: As simple as `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments_id NOT IN (SELECT the_comment_id FROM hide_comment)`?

Comment: `WHERE ORDER BY comment_date` Really? How's that working for you?